# Point free style with infix notation

Tags: haskell, pointfree

Hello is there a way to write point free style when using infix notation?

```
f::Int->Int->Int->Int
f a b=(+) (a+b)
```

Why you cannot do something like this ?

```
 f::Int->Int->Int->Int
 f a b=(a+b) +

      or

 f a b= (a+b) `+`
```

Can you not combine operators in point free style like e.g?

```
ptfree::Int->Int->Int->Int
ptfree=(+) (+)
```

I mean you can chop arguments of functions like `fold` but why not for operator arguments?

Comment: Do you mean completely point-free? The only completely point-free example you have given is the last one.

Comment: Yes, can you do it completely point-free?

Comment: What are you intending the last three examples to do? They only take 2 arguments, according to the type signatures.

Comment: I edited i am sorry !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well since you need to pass *two* parameters, we can use what is known as the "*surprised owl operator*". This is basically a composition of parameters. So we can use:

```
f = ((.).(.)) (+) (+)
```

Or we can more inline the operator like:

```
f = ((+) .) . (+)
```

The owl operator `((.).(.)) f g` basically is short for `\x y -> f (g x y)`

**How does this work?**

The canonical form of the "*surprised owl operator*" is:

```
= ((.) . (.))
------------- (canonical form)
  (.) (.) (.)
```

So we can now replace the `(.)`s with corresponding lambda expressions:

```
(\f g x -> f (g x)) (.) (.)
```

So now we can perform some replacements:

```
   (\f g x -> f (g x)) (.) (.)
-> (\x -> (.) ((.) x))
-> (\x -> (\q r y -> q (r y)) ((.) x))
-> (\x -> (\r y -> ((.) x) (r y)))
-> (\x r y -> ((.) x) (r y))
-> (\x r y -> ((\s t u -> s (t u)) x) (r y))
-> (\x r y -> (\t u -> x (t u)) (r y))
-> (\x r y -> (\u -> x ((r y) u)))
-> \x r y u -> x ((r y) u))
-> \x r y u -> x (r y u)
```

So basically it means that our surprised owl operator, is equal to:

```
surprised_owl :: (y -> z) -> (a -> b -> y) -> a -> b -> z
surprised_owl f g x y = f (g x y)  -- renamed variables
```

And if we now specialize this with the fuctions provided (two times `(+)`), we get:

```
f = surprised_owl (+) (+)
```

so:

```
f x y = (+) ((+) x y)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 3):

You must compose `(+)` with `(+)` twice, for it to be completely point-free: `f = ((+) .) . (+)`

Recall that composition is defined as

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

or, equivalently:

```
(f . g) = \x -> f (g x)
```

So, if you look at the composition `f = ((+) .) . (+)` and work backwards using the definition of `(.)`:

```
f       = ((+) .) . (+)
f       = \x -> ((+) .) ((+) x)          -- definition of (.)
f       = \y -> (\x -> (+) (((+) x) y))  -- definition of (.)
f x y   = (+) (((+) x) y)                -- a simpler way to write this
f x y z = (+) (((+) x) y) z              -- explicitly add in the final argument (eta expansion)
f x y z = ((+) x y) + z                  -- rewrite as infix
f x y z = (x + y) + z                    -- rewrite as infix
```

and you see we end up with what we started before we tried to make it point-free, so we know that this definition works. Going the other way through the steps above, roughly bottom-to-top, could give you an idea of how you might find such a point-free definition of a function like `f`.

When you "leave off" multiple arguments from the "end" like this, you usually must compose multiple times. Working through a few similar functions should help build intuition for this.

Note: I wouldn't generally recommend using this sort of point-free (when it complicates things) in production code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir !