# Transforming a function in Haskell to point free notation

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I have a function in haskell on paper as an example:

```
function2 a b c = (a * b) + c
```

and I'm required to write the example in point free notation. I'm really bad at working with point free style as I find it really confusing with no proper guide through it so i gave it a try:

```
function2 a b c = (a * b) + c
function2 a b c = ((*) a b) + c #operator sectioning
function2 a b c = (+) ((*) a b)c #operator sectioning once more
#I'm stuck here now
```

I wasnt sure what should come up next as that was the limit i could think of for this example. Would appreciate some help on this.

--Second example:

```
function3 a b = a `div` (g b)
function3 a b = `div` a (g b) --operator sectioning
function3 a b = (`div` a) (g b) --parentheses
function3 a b = ((`div` a g).)b --B combinator
function3 a   = ((`div` a g).) --eta conversion
function3 a   = ((.)(`div` a g)) --operator sectioning
function3 a   = ((.)flip(`div` g a))
function3 a   = ((.)flip(`div` g).a) --B combinator
function3     = ((.)flip(`div` g)) --eta conversion (complete)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply the **B** combinator (i.e. `(f . g) x = f (g x)`) there:

```
function2 a b c = (a * b) + c
function2 a b c = ((*) a b) + c    -- operator sectioning
function2 a b c = (+) ((*) a b) c  -- operator sectioning once more
      = (+) (((*) a) b) c          -- explicit parentheses
      = ((+) . ((*) a)) b c        -- B combinator
      = ((.) (+) ((*) a)) b c      -- operator sectioning 
      = ((.) (+) . (*)) a b c      -- B combinator
```

Indeed the types are the same:

```
> :t let function2 a b c = (a * b) + c in function2
let function2 a b c = (a * b) + c in function2
  :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> a

> :t ((.) (+) . (*))
((.) (+) . (*)) :: Num b => b -> b -> b -> b
```

We work by extricating the arguments one by one in the correct order, to end up with

```
function2 a b c = (......) a b c
```

so that the *eta-contraction* can be applied to get rid of the explicit arguments,

```
function2       = (......)
```

Our *tools* in this, which we get to apply *in both directions*, are

```
S a b c  =  (a c) (b c)  =  (a <*> b) c
K a b    =  a            =  const a b
I a      =  a            =  id a
B a b c  =  a (b c)      =  (a . b) c
C a b c  =  a c b        =  flip a b c
W a b    =  a b b        =  join a b
U a      =  a a          -- not in Haskell: `join id` has no type
```

There's also `(f =<< g) x = f (g x) x = join (f . g) x`.

Some more, useful patterns that emerge when we work with pointfree for a while are:

```
((f .) .) g x y = f (g x y)
(((f .) .) .) g x y z = f (g x y z)
.....
((. g) . f) x y = f x (g y)
((. g) . f . h) x y = f (h x) (g y)
```

---

(update.) There's an error near the start in your second example, invalidating all the following steps after it:

```
function3 a b = a `div` (g b)
function3 a b = -- `div` a (g b)     -- wrong syntax, you meant
                div a (g b)
function3 a b = -- (`div` a) (g b)   -- wrong; it is
                (a `div`) (g b) --operator sectioning
function3 a b = ((a `div`) . g) b --B combinator
function3 a   = (div a . g) --eta conversion; back with plain syntax
function3 a   = (.) (div a) g --operator sectioning
function3 a   = flip (.) g (div a) --definition of flip
function3 a   = (flip (.) g . div) a --B combinator
function3     = (flip (.) g . div) --eta conversion
              = (.) (flip (.) g) div  --operator section
```

So yeah, some of the steps were in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. How is `((.) (+) ((*) a)) b c = ((.) (+) . (*)) a b c`? What is `f` and `g` here if this were perceived as `(f . g) x = f (g x)`?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi `f = (.) (+) = ((.) (+)) ; g = (*) ; (f (g a)) == (f . g) a`. `b, c` are just hanging, irrelevant for *this* transformation. extraneous parentheses are also irrelevant.

Comment: @WillNess thanks for the thorough explanation previously. So based on it, I've worked on another example i attempted in the updated post above, would appreciate if you could assess it and inform me if I'm right with the rules.

Comment: @WillNess thank you. One question, why is it that its div a (g b) then reverted back to (a `div`) (g b)? Does the ` ` play a role in the change?

Comment: it was unnecessary in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

We can continue with:

```
function2 a b = (+) ((*) a b)     [eta-reduction]
function2 a = (+) . (*) a         [using a dot, to eliminate the b]
function2 = ((.) . (.)) (+) (*)   ["blackbird" operator to pass two parameters]
```

Here the ["blackbird operator"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-aviary-0.4.0/docs/Data-Aviary-Birds.html#v:blackbird) is a combination of three [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.) operators. It is functionally equivalent to:

```
((.) . (.)) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
((.) . (.)) f g x y = f (g x y)
```

see here for a [derivation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50852623/67579).

Comment: I presume you’re calling it “owl” to avoid the fact that people in practice refer to it as a different kind of hooters, but in the usual aviary of [combinator birds](http://www.angelfire.com/tx4/cus/combinator/birds.html), the owl O is λfg.g(fg); this is the blackbird B₁ = λfgxy.f(gxy), sometimes spelled `(.:)`, `(...)`, or `fmap fmap fmap` if you want to be silly about it. For my pointfree code though, I prefer to just add an `fmap`—`fmap (+) . (*)`—since even though it’s just composition here, semantically I think of it as “mapping over” the extra argument.